# VSCode ESLint on save - for Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, eslint, visual-studio-code, vetur

[image]

I'm new to [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) in vscode and vue.js

I ran `yarn add -D eslint eslint-plugin-vue` and have this `"eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.1.1"` in my ***package.json***

I have a file at the root of my folder

**.eslintrc**

```
{
    "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
    "vue/html-self-closing": "off"
    }
}
```

I also have this in my settings.json

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
"vetur.validation.template": true,
```

I tried to, purposely spell `component` wrong.

```
<script>
import Task from "./Task.vue"

export default {
    name: "Tasks",
    props: {
        tasks: Array
    },
    component: {
        Task
    }
}
</script>
```

When I saved the file, It didn't stop me and highlight that I spelled wrong.

[image]

What did I do wrong here ?

Can someone please help me get my VSCode going with eslint for vue.js ?

Comment: Vue allows adding custom options to the component declaration, so `component` wouldn't be considered a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found a way to prevent this specific typo, but adding this to your rules inside  `.eslintrc` file would give you a heads up next time.

```
"vue/no-restricted-component-options": [
        "error",
        {
            "name": "component",
            "message": "Use \"components\" instead."
        }
    ]
```

Comment: cool work around will do. Thanks.